# FuzzyWuzzy Process question - How to use columns after fuzzy matching

Tags: python, anaconda, fuzzywuzzy

I am looking to de-duplicate Customer Records as part of a project looking at a dataset with roughly 2000 customers.
Firstly, we don't have any unique values in our columns

We have CustomerID, Firstname, lastname, middlename, phone#, email addr, billing addr.

This is largely a process question.
Once I generate my set of matches using fuzzywyzzy.token_sort_ratio. I understand how to compare the results to a ratio and write them to a list, but my question is generally how do I sort them with other columns to find which are unique and which are duplicates.

For example, I have multiple John Does (some with middlenames, some missing phone #, some missing email addr) and there are several unique and several duplicate values.

It's how I then use my new column with other columns to combine a list of customerids belonging to the same customer.

Any advice would be appreciated. thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include a sample data of your question and your desired output. Also, if you have tried any code , please update it in the post too. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.